# Run non-spark python code on spark to use its distributive compute to optimize the performance

Tags: python, apache-spark, spark-submit

Can I use my existing native python code (non-pyspark code) in spark to use its fast processing and distributed feature? I do not want to edit my existing python code to make it pyspark code... and just want to run it as it-is in spark(stand-alone)?? is it possible to do using spark-submit or any other way so that I can avail spark and run my non-spark python code? I would really appreciate anyone's help/steps to overcome this problem?

TIA.

P.S: I am trying to do spark-submit on a linux server(having spark installed) but unable to achieve this

Example,
abc.py is a python script having non-pyspark, native python code
I cannot make changes to the code but want to run the above python file in spark to use its distributive compute, can I do that using spark-submit or any other way??
Note: I can not make any changes to the python file I have and this python file has no code written in pyspark

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Without using RDD's or rather DataFrames in the main these days, no parallelization will occur. Nor for pandas dataframe.

That is to say, no point in running on Spark. Can run it on Databricks of course and minimize platforms.

Comment: Hi thebluephantom, Thank you for your response. I get your point but the thing is we are planning to gradually modify the code to pyspark but as of now we want to use the existing non-pyspark python code on the spark server and later move to changing the scripts, so just want to know if there is a way to run a non-spark python code file in spark to take advantage of it distributive computing

Comment: OK, that is a nuance. But you can do that, but it will run single-thread initially. Pls accept answer. The spark submit should be a separate question. Pls supply more details, the people around here can eb very hard if no code or not enough text. Success.

Comment: How to do that? Any help would be greatly appreciated @thebluephantom

Comment: Click on up arrow or on the tick.

Comment: I did that but can you help me with the way to execute the non-pyspark python code?

Comment: You need to post another question; otherwise some may down vote or close for no focus. Notify me when you have done.

Comment: Look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59669493/how-to-submit-a-pyspark-job-by-using-spark-submit

Comment: thebluephantom, I have updated this one already , please have a look

Comment: Actually taking answer away and chging question. On your own

Comment: Didn't get what you mean @ 
thebluephantom

Comment: Wifi glitch. Excuses. What should i look at? U need new question.

Comment: I have already updated this question itself

Comment: No u should raise a new question. How can u update an answered question? Pls follow protocol

Comment: oh ok, my bad, apologies for the same.  here you go @
thebluephantom      https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78140013/can-i-use-spark-submit-to-run-a-non-pyspark-python-code-on-spark-that-is-witho?noredirect=1#comment137765429_78140013

Comment: Looks like a comprehensive answer there.

Comment: Didn't get you @ 
thebluephantom