# Can I use spark-submit to run a non-pyspark python code on spark, that is, without or with minimal changes?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-submit

Can I use spark-submit to run a non-pyspark python code on spark, that is, without or with minimal changes?
Example,
abc.py is a python script having non-pyspark, native python code
I cannot make changes to the code but want to run the above python file in spark to use its distributive compute, can I do that using spark-submit or any other way??
Note: I can not make any changes to the python file I have and this python file has no code written in pyspark

abc.py is a python script having non-pyspark, native python code
I cannot make changes to the code but want to run the above python file in spark to use its distributive compute, can I do that using spark-submit or any other way??
Note: I can not make any changes to the python file I have and this python file has no code written in pyspark

Comment: @mazaneicha thanks for your response but I am unclear with this blog you shared, I want to know more details, if I can run a non-pyspark python code and use the spark distributive compute capability as well. Could you please help on this

Comment: This question could be answered more easily if there were more info on these python scripts; why can you not change them, what dependencies do they have, why do you think that the pyspark environment would not support them?

Comment: Hi LinFelix, I cannot provide the full code as it huge one....but the script uses mix of python libraries (numpy, pandas.,sqlalchemy, boto .etc..ray for parallization )...We will eventually convert the code to pyspark but as of now the expertise is what we are developing in pyspark/spark, so just to start with we want to re-use the existing non-pyspark python code as is and execute it on spark to use its distribute/compute...how can I achieve this

Comment: @mazaneicha Can you please help in here

Comment: I guess I know where the confusion is. Nothing can be executed "ON Spark" except Spark itself, i.e. the applications that use Spark API. If you want to parallelize execution of something else, I think you should be looking at other technologies, like kubernetes, docker, etc. etc.